# How to find virtual memory size and cache size of a linux system?

Tags: linux

Is there any command to get virtual memory size, cache size and front side bus speed of a linux system?

Comment: Not programming related, should be moved to superuser.

Answer (score 5):

`free`, `/proc/cpuinfo`, `lshw`, `lspci`, etc. which one do you want?

Answer (score 0):

Using `top` you can see lots of interactive information of your system